# debug lid open/close events

Tags: suspend, lid

Running 16.10 on a Late 2016 Razer Blade Stealth laptop.  When I close the lid, it goes to suspend properly.  When I wake it by opening the lid, it stays awake for maybe 10-15s then goes back to sleep.  How do I start debugging this?  I don't consider disabling this feature a solution.

Comment: As I told you before, your hardware is still not very well supported. Keep updating and it will be solved eventually.

Comment: That answer is insufficient and *extremely unsatisfactory*.  Why wait when I can learn to fix it myself?

Comment: NOT and answer, comment. There a difference and a big one!

Comment: Both *comments* are a waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the kernel command line `button.lid_init_state=open` fixes the issue.  Not sure if this should get fixed in Ubuntu or where.

```
sudo vi /etc/default/grub
```

change:

```
-GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="drm.debug=0xe plymouth:debug"
+GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="drm.debug=0xe plymouth:debug button.lid_init_state=open"
```

then:

```
sudo update-grub
sudo shutdown -r now
```

Bit thanks to reddit user /u/HerpDerpHerpderpsen for this solution.  See [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/razer/comments/5orvy5/late_2016_rbs_qhd_linux_damage_report/) for updates.

Note: this doesn't help debug lid events, but in that thread I'll try to get more info.